# An array in main reffering to an array outside main

Tags: java, arrays, reference

I'm trying to create an array in my main by making it identical to an array created in a method outside my main. I cant think of any way to do this...

Here's my code:

```
public class GRID {     
    public void createGrid() {
        int N = StdIn.readInt();
        int thisarray[][] = new int[N][N];
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++) {
                int n = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
                thisarray[x][y] = n;                
            }
        }

    }
    public static void main(String []args){     
        GRID g = new GRID();
        int [][] newArray = //thisarray 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for this answer? I have changed the return type of method to `int[][]`
and inside main method we can call `createGrid` method to get `int[][]`

```
public class GRID {     
    public int[][] createGrid() {
        int N = StdIn.readInt();
        int thisarray[][] = new int[N][N];
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++) {
                int n = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
                thisarray[x][y] = n;                
            }
        }
        return thisarray;

    }
    public static void main(String []args){     
        GRID g = new GRID();
        int [][] newArray = g.createGrid();
    }
}
```

If you want `newArray` on basis of `N` then send `N` to `createGrid` method. For this you will have to add one parameter in `createGrid` method like given below. Remove `StdIn.readInt()`  from `createGrid` method

```
public class GRID {     
    public int[][] createGrid(int N) {
        int thisarray[][] = new int[N][N];
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++) {
                int n = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
                thisarray[x][y] = n;                
            }
        }
        return thisarray;

    }
    public static void main(String []args){     
        GRID g = new GRID();
        int [][] newArray = g.createGrid(StdIn.readInt());  //new array everytime on the basis of input value.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change return type of createGrid() from void to int[][]

```
public class GRID 
{

public int[][] createGrid() {
    int N = StdIn.readInt();
      int thisarray[][] = new int[N][N];
    for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
        for (int y = 0; y < N; y++) {
            int n = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
            thisarray[x][y] = n;
        }
    }
   return thisarray;
}
public static void main(String []args)
{
   GRID g = new GRID();
   int [][] newArray = g.createGrid(); 
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `thisarray` a `static` instance of the class (since its used in `static main`)

```
public class GRID {

    private static int[][] thisarray;

    public void createGrid() {
        int N = StdIn.readInt();
        thisarray = new int[N][N];
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++) {
                int n = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
                thisarray[x][y] = n;

            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String []args){
        GRID g = new GRID();
        g.createGrid();
        int [][] newArray = thisarray; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `return thisarray;` in `createGrid()` method (also change the return type from `void` to `int[][]`) and in main you will have:

```
int [][] newArray = g.createGrid()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class GRID {  
    //Declare your array here   
    private int thisarray[][];
    public void createGrid() {
        int N = StdIn.readInt();
        thisarray[][] = new int[N][N];
        for (int x = 0; x < N; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++) {
                int n = (int) (Math.random() * 6 + 1);
                thisarray[x][y] = n;                
            }
        }

    }
    public static void main(String []args){     
        GRID g = new GRID();
        //Then you can use it in the main
        int [][] newArray = thisarray; 
    }
```

}